# Where can I find a map or list of 19th century European watermills?

Tags: maps

I am looking for a *map* or *list* of 19. century [watermills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watermill).

I have found [this](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magyarorsz%C3%A1g_malmainak_list%C3%A1ja#V%C3%ADzimalmok) Hungarian Wikipedia page, which contains many historical watermills, but only within the current or historic territory of Hungary. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_watermills) article in English is very limited in scope.

**Is there an accessible map / list which contains 19. century watermills?**

Comment: ["Rural water mills began to close down to be replaced by the large, industrial, port-based steam-powered mill and by the end of the 19th Century almost all rural watermills had ceased commercial production."](http://www.jesmonddeneoldmill.org.uk/mill/technology.html)

Comment: Probably a subset of [this map](https://www.buildinghistory.org/buildings/mills.shtml)

Comment: I think you'll find numerous national lists, and have to put them together into an European one yourself.